# IntelliJ Scala - Calling a Function's .curried

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, functional-programming, currying, intellij-14

I'm trying to curry a method like so in a Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ IDEA.

`def add1(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y`

So I tell Scala to convert my method to a funtion using _

`val add1func = add1 _` gives `(Int, Int) => Int = <function2>`

All good. Now I try to call .curried;

`val add1curry = add1func.curried`

I get a exception;

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Function2.curried$mcIII$sp()Lscala/Function1;
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(test-worksheet.sc0.tmp:3)
```

Any ideas what is going on? This works in the Scala REPL.

Comment: this works for me in the Scala REPL -- how are you compiling/running this code?

Comment: works for me too, I guess some problem with class path. Heres output from console: https://gist.github.com/ezhulenev/f5ffcb7859f00510ca1b

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this works in the scala REPL. Its IntelliJ's Scala Worksheet. Editing...